# PHP Format Multidimensional Object as Select Drop Down with Depth

Tags: php, object, recursion, categories

How can I take the following and echo it as a beautiful formatted select drop down including '--' for each level?

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => First Category
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 4
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => HTML Times
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => Email Ninja
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => Taco Night
            [parent_id] => 0
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => SSH
            [parent_id] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 10
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [title] => Root Commands
                            [parent_id] => 7
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 11
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [title] => Shell
                            [parent_id] => 7
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 12
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [title] => Linux
                            [parent_id] => 7
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 13
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [title] => Windows
                            [parent_id] => 7
                        )

                )

        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 8
            [user_id] => 6
            [title] => Dinner Tonight
            [parent_id] => 0
            [childs] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [user_id] => 6
                            [title] => Mexican
                            [parent_id] => 8
                            [childs] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [id] => 14
                                            [user_id] => 6
                                            [title] => Tacos
                                            [parent_id] => 9
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I know this topic is pretty heavily covered, but it's not making a whole lot of since to me. After two days of reading... and reading... and reading... I was finally able to get this data out of my database. Now, I can't seem to get it to echo out any deeper than the first category.

Thanks for the assistance and patience.

Here's how I'm getting the parents currently:

> $level = 0;
>
> $categories = $this->mycrate->build_categories();
>
> ```
>     echo '<select class="input-block-level">';
>
>     function RecursiveWrite($categories) {
>         foreach ($categories as $category) {
>             echo '<option value="'.$category->id.'">'.$category->title.'</option>';
>             RecursiveWrite($category->parent_id);
>         }
>     }
>
>     RecursiveWrite($categories);
>
>     echo '</select>';
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function RecursiveWrite($categories) {
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        echo '<option value="'.$category->id.'">'.$category->title.'</option>';
        RecursiveWrite($category->childs);
    }
}

RecursiveWrite($categories);
```

Try that to start, the recursive part needs to be called on the children elements, not the parent ID.

Comment: Thanks for the help. As it is, the function is pulling the first level of subcategories but stops there.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was right in the first place - you do need a recursive function... My bad. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yep! That gets all of them. I think I can handle getting the levels with the appropriate '--' from there. I greatly appreciate your help!!